# Creating a hubtile like Pictures Hub on Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I want to create a hubtile (from Silverlight Toolkit for WP) to be similar to Picture Hub. I mean, a background image that moves inside the tile. How to create this animation? Maybe I'm told is not too clear, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use the HubTile control:

http://igrali.com/2011/08/19/how-to-use-the-hubtile-control/

You can even make it larger in width, although it's not recommended.

EDIT: If I misunderstood the question and you want the Ken Burns effect, here's something to get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211958/A-Ken-Burns-powered-photo-frame-control-for-WPF

Comment: I think he's trying to replicate the 'Ken Burns Effect' on the main photo app - I don't think the HubTile is the solution.

Comment: it is not exactly what I mean, sorry